# Orthogonality of Meyer Wavelets

Tags: fourier-analysis, wavelets

I am reading on Meyer wavelets and have trouble understanding the proof of the orthogonality of the shifted wavelets. The definitions are as follows:

$\eta \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a scaling function that satisfies the following:

- $H_r := \overline{\mathrm{span}}\{\eta\left(\frac{\cdot-n}{2^r}\right) | ~r \in \mathbb{Z},~ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
- $H_r \subset H_{r+1}$
- $\hat{\eta}$ is continous and $\sum_{l\in\mathbb{Z}} |\hat{\eta}(p+2\pi l)|^2$ has no zeroes.

Then $\varphi$ is defined via

$$\hat{\varphi}(p) = \hat{\eta}(p)~\left(\sum_{l\in\mathbb{Z}} |\hat{\eta}(p+2\pi l)|^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

and the claim

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(x-m)^* \varphi(x-n)\, \mathrm{d}x = \delta_{mn}~~ \forall m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

is made.
I have trouble proving the last statement. This is how far I got:
For simplicity assume wlog $m=0$. Then the statement translates in the Fourier domain to (up to some normalization factors)

$$\int  e^{ipn}\hat{\varphi}(p)^*\hat{\varphi}(p) \, \mathrm{d}p= \int e^{ipn} \frac{\hat{\eta}(p)^* \hat{\eta}(p)}{\sum_{l\in\mathbb{Z}} |\hat{\eta}(p+2\pi l)|^2} \, \mathrm{d}p = \delta_{n0}$$

and now we have a $2\pi$-*periodic, real, positive* and *even* denominator and $\hat{\eta}(p)^* \hat{\eta}(p) = \hat{\eta}(-p)~ \hat{\eta}(p)$ is a *positive, even* and *real* functions, due to the realness of $\eta$. So I can see, that the imaginary part of the integral vanishes as an integral over an odd function. But I can't see, why the real part should vanish too. Which of of the additional properties of $\eta$ do I have to use and how?

**edit**

now following @Dunham s advice I get the following,

$$ = \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\cos(p n)}{g(p)} \hat{\eta}(p+2 j \pi)^* \hat{\eta} (p+2 j \pi) \mathbb{d}p$$

$$ = 2 \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}}  \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\cos(p n)}{g(p)}   \hat{\eta}(-p-2 j \pi) \hat{\eta} (p+2 j \pi) \mathbb{d}p $$

where

$$ g(p) =  \sum_{l\in\mathbb{Z}} |\hat{\eta}(p+2\pi l)|^2$$

and $e^{ipn}$ was split in its real and imaginary part and the imaginary integral already vanishes.

However I still can't see, why it vanishes. Obviously in this situation every summand must individually vanish, but why can't $\frac{\hat{\eta}(-p-2 j \pi) \hat{\eta} (p+2 j \pi)}{g(p)}$ have most of its contribution to the integral, where cos is positive and almost none, where it is negative?

**edit** adding the final answer, in case somebody else stumbles upon this...

$$
... = \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(np) \frac{\sum_{l\in\mathbb{Z}} |\hat{\eta}(p+2\pi l)|^2}{\sum_{l\in\mathbb{Z}} |\hat{\eta}(p+2\pi l)|^2} \mathrm{d}p = \delta_{n0}
$$

Cheers, Jan Lukas

Comment: periodize the domain, change variables, and add the integrals

Comment: @Dunham I followed your advice, as you can see in my edit. Still I can't get the integrals to vanish

Comment: Consider your penultimate equation. interchange the integral and sum. Then recall that $a^*a=|a|^2$.

Comment: Okay, finally got it... Thanks alot! @Dunham

Comment: I suggest posting your calculation as an answer